# Problem with finding folder in C:\ driver in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, directory, iteration, c++17

My code is shown below. I want to iterate a C:\ drive entirely; however, the output does not have the folders, "Users", "Windows", etc. There are only these:

```
C:\$SysReset
C:\$WINDOWS.~BT
C:\$Windows.~WS
C:\$WinREAgent
C:\Config.Msi
C:\Documents and Settings
```

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    for (const auto& el : std::filesystem::directory_iterator
    (L"C:\\", std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink |
        std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
    {
        std::string filess = el.path().string();

        if (filess.find("$Recycle.Bin") != std::string::npos)
            continue;
        if (is_directory(el))
            std::cout << el.path().string() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I want to know the reason of such output and why there is no "Users" folder.

Comment: On my system `is_directory` throws an exception for files like `pagefile.sys` because of a sharing violation. If I wrap that code in a `try/catch` and eat the exception it lists all the directories.

Comment: Alternatively, use the overloaded version of `is_directory()` that outputs a `std::error_code`, then no exception will be thrown, and thus no `try/catch` will be needed. Also, note that `directory_entry` has overloaded `is_directory()` methods of its own.